# iOS app missing splash screen, new black borders and ui glitching after visualstudio 8.10.10 and xcode 13 update

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xcode13

Just updated to Xcode 13 and Visualstudio Mac to 8.10.10. Since then my app:

- Wont display the splash screen.
- The app is cropped at top and bottom.
- Ui is acting generally weird.

Now I have read old threads on similar problems and adding the **Launch screen interface file base name.** in the info.plist file does make the app cover the whole screen.

I have tried switching splash screens and change location. But it's just black. I don't use a storyboard for the splash and instead provide several different resolutions, which have worked fine for several years.

The UI is glitching like the loader picture, and several different ui elements where colors are provided are "cut" in the middle showing two colors when it should switch.

I have read the release notes for xcode13 but haven't found anything related that would break the whole UI.

The interface glitching and no splash screen I can't seem to find a solution for. Everything worked fine before the update.

What could be the problem? Some setting in the info.plist, a checkbox in the storyboard?

I'm still new to Xamarin and iOS development and greatly accept suggestions.
Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Thanks

iOS load glitch [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL2vZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your statement, you are not using a storyboard, so you need to replace the **Launch Screen** with a **LaunchImage**, then check the LaunchImage file (if it does not exist, you need to create it yourself) and add all strictly standardized pictures inside.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. Yes, there was a setting in the plist file - LaunchScreen, that messed up the launch screen. Thanks for your answer. 
Other general weird stuff was the simulators acting up, and has somewhat been fixed in xcode updates. Thanks